# ns2 installation Permission denied

Tags: ns2

The following error , while trying to install ns-2.33 on ubuntu 12.04. 
    How can i solve  this problem

```
m -f embedded-tcl.cc
./tcl2c++ et_tcl ../lib/tcl8.4/init.tcl ../lib/tcl8.4/history.tcl ../lib/tcl8.4/word.tcl            ../lib/tcl8.4/http1.0/http.tcl > embedded-tcl.cc
/bin/sh: 1: ./tcl2c++: Permission denied
make: *** [embedded-tcl.cc] Error 126
tclcl-1.19 make failed! Exiting ...
See http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html for problems
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install with Root permission. i think ubuntu have default ns. check /usr/bin folder.